# how to enroll students into categories in Moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

Can somebody tell me how to enroll students to categories instead for each courses.

Regards,
Sandesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1:**
You have to enable **Category Enrolment** plugin to enrol students to a category. To enable this plugin go to *Site Administration-->Plugins-->Enrolments-->Manage enrol plugins*.

**Step 2:**
Now add the context **Category** to student. Go to open *Site administration-->Users-->Permissions-->Define roles*, click on the student role, click on the edit button and click on the checkbox associated with **Category**.

On the same page, provide access to **enrol/category:synchronised** for student by selecting **Allow**. and save the changes.

**Step 3:**
Visit *Site Administration-->Courses-->Add/Edit Courses* and click on the category. From the **Category Settings**, Click on **Assign Roles**, select the users and add them to the category.

Now you can confirm enrolment by going to *Course Setting-->Users-->Enrolled Users*

---

However, it is recommended that you use the **Cohort Sync** to enrol students to a Category. Cohorts are very easy to setup and manage.

More details here:

http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Category_enrolments

http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Cohort_sync

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply gnuwings, I enabled category enrolment and made necessary changes as you mentioned above.. but I am not able to see the option to enroll students to categories.. please help me..

Comment: It's through Role assignment and explained in the last section of http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Category_enrolments

Comment: I have modified the answer with more explanation. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the category page clicking on (in left bar) Site administration » Courses » Add/edit courses.

You just have to go to the category page (click on the name of the category you want) and then link on the "Assign roles" located in left bar, under "Settings".

This way you can assign the roles you want: students, teachers, etc.

ED

Comment: To be specific, Role assignment and category enrolment are different.